# Para qué sirve hacer propiedades privadas en clases de Python

Tags: python

No entiendo bien para qué sirve hacer una propiedad privada en una clase. Sé que es para que sólo se pueda acceder desde la propia clase, pero si despues creamos un método que cambia esa propiedad... No entiendo muy bien.

Tengo este código que me pasaron de un libro de Python para intentar aclararme, pero no lo han conseguido.

```
class Persona:
  def __init__(self):
    self.__nombre= "Ingresa un nombre"
    self.__apellido= "Ingresa un apellido"

  def nombre(self, nombre):
    if (nombre != ' '): return nombre
    else: return self.__nombre
```

¿De qué sirve tener una función (método en este caso) que retorne un nombre? ¿No sería lo mismo hacer una propiedad `self.nombre` y cambiarla cuando se requiera?

Comment: En python no existen propiedades privadas

Comment: ¿Puedes ser más concreto? Lo que comentas es más complejo de lo que parece y no quisiera liarte más de lo necesario con la explicación. Mejor si añades algún código a la pregunta.

Comment: Va de acuerdo al programador, pero en python las propiedades y métodos privados no existen, por lo que son facilmente sobreescribibles, sin embargo por convencion puedes hacer una propiedad o metodo "privado" si empieza con el caracter `_`, que de lo unico que te puede servir es a no ser importado cuando haces algo como esto `from mi_library import *`, en este caso, las funciones, variables, clases, metodos, que empiezen con `_` no serán importadas, del resto tener propiedades o metodos privados en python es desicion del programador, votare para cerrar esta pregunta por lo amplia que puede ser

Answer (score 2):

En realidad, en Python no hay atributos privados como tal. Se usa determinada nomenclatura por convención y dependiendo de tu API tendrá sentido o no usar unas cosas u otras.

Atributos públicos: Se llaman de forma normal

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self, nombre):
        self.nombre = nombre

ex = Example('Pepe')
print(ex.nombre) ## >> 'Pepe'
```

Atributos protegidos: Se usa un guión bajo delante. Con ello indicas al usuario que ese atributo no es recomendable usarlo tal cual ya que puede estar sujeto a cambios en futuras versiones, es para consumo interno de subclases, uso interno de la propia clase,... De la misma forma que no se recomienda usarlo no se debería modificar. No es privado ya que se puede acceder sin problemas.

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        self._nombre = 'Pepe'

ex = Example()
print(ex._nombre) ## >> 'Pepe'
```

Atributos 'privados': No existen como tal en Python pero se usa en mecanismo conocido como *name mangling* para que el atributo de turno no sea tan directamente accesible y para *anexar* la funcionalidad al nombre de la clase y evitar conflictos de nombres, por ejemplo, al heredar. Los atributos privados se definen usando doble guión bajo delante del nombre.

```
# ejemplo de la documentación oficial para no reinventar la rueda :-D
class Mapping:
    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self.items_list = []
        self.__update(iterable)

    def update(self, iterable):
        for item in iterable:
            self.items_list.append(item)

    __update = update   # private copy of original update() method

class MappingSubclass(Mapping):

    def update(self, keys, values):
        # provides new signature for update()
        # but does not break __init__()
        for item in zip(keys, values):
            self.items_list.append(item)
```

Referencias:

- [Doc oficial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables)
- [Name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Python)

Answer (score 0):

Las propiedades o métodos privados son en realidad para uso interno.

A veces es o son necesarios variables o métodos auxiliares para cumplir con el objetivo de la clase. Estos métodos o variables no son necesarios exponerlos o mostrarlos fuera de la clase. En base a esto es que los lenguajes orientados a objetos tienen mecanismos para ocultarlos.

Te recomiendo esta lectura: [Las propiedades privadas en Python](https://www.genbetadev.com/python/cazadores-de-mitos-las-propiedades-privadas-en-python)